# UIPopoverController is not so with a color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

Does anyone know why is appearing white part? My View is already gray, but gets two white pieces

[image]

whites: Arrow and final Popover!

[UPDATE]

this is the code that calls the popover and makes the arrow points to the button that was clicked!

```
- (void) buttonFilter {

    if (viewFilter == @"Artistas") {
        content = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TipoArtistaViewController"]; // MUDAR PARA O NOVO FILTRO DE ARTISTAS
    } else if (viewFilter == @"Músicas") {
        content = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CategoriaViewController"];
    }

    [self callFilter:btnFilter Filter:content];
}

- (void)callFilter:(id)sender Filter:(UIViewController *) content{
    self.currentPop = popoverController;

    popoverController = [[WYPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:content];

    UIButton * bt = (UIButton * )sender;
    UIView *view = [bt valueForKey:@"view"];
    popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 180);
    popoverController.delegate = self;
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:view.bounds inView:view permittedArrowDirections:WYPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
 }
```

the next is where to mount the session:

```
//extend and collpase
- (void)setupViewController {

    categoriaBD = [categoriaDAO selectCategoria];


    self.data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < [categoriaBD count]; i++)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary * teste = [categoriaBD objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];
        ID = [[teste objectForKey:@"1"] integerValue];
        subcategoriaBD = [categoriaDAO selectSubCategoriaByCategoriaID:ID];

        NSMutableArray* section = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int j = 0; j < [subcategoriaBD count]; j++)
        {
            NSMutableDictionary * subCat = [subcategoriaBD objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", j]];
            [section addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:[subCat objectForKey:@"1"]]];
        }
        [self.data addObject:section];                      
    }

    self.headers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < [categoriaBD count]; i++)
    {

        NSString *inStr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i", (int)i];
        nomeCategoria = [categoriaBD objectForKey:inStr];

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 310, 40)];
        [label setText:[nomeCategoria objectForKey:@"2"]];

        UIView* header = [[UIView alloc] init];

        [header setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(226/255.0) green:(226/255.0) blue:(226/255.0) alpha:1]];
        [header addSubview:label];
        [self.headers addObject:header];

    }
}
```

Comment: please mention bit more detail about designpart. like, you are  you are using autolayout or autoresize or how you configure your popovercontroller etc otherwise no one can help you in such a small description.

Comment: Could you show the code you're using?

Comment: yes sure. I will update the POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to create a custom [`UIPopoverBackgroundView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverBackgroundView_class/index.html) subclass that sets the properties of the arrow you want.

```
popoverController.popoverBackgroundViewClass = [MyPopoverBackgroundView class];
```